# Using Tweepy to fetch recent Tweets from a specific location

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to fetch the recent Tweets from a specified location which can be either city/country. I went through the Tweepy documentation and followed the snippets as mentioned but it looks like I'm missing something here.

```
# the coordinates and params
lat = 28
long = 77
granularity = 'city'
max_results = 1
  
# fetching the locations 
locations = tweepy.api.reverse_geocode(lat=lat, long=long, granularity=granularity, max_results=max_results)
```

[image]

It would be helpful if someone can point out what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

`tweepy.api` is an unauthenticated instance of [`tweepy.API`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#tweepy.API).
You need to instantiate your own instance of `API` using your authentication/credentials.